# jQuery file upload large file issues

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

This plugin works great for 16bit or less audio file uploads but it does not seem to work for 24 bit audio file. Anyone have a solution to get 24bit files to upload correctly?
plugin: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: is it showing some error?

Comment: My users were reporting a time out. Are there other settings for files bigger than 100mb? and high quality

Comment: I think it is not the problem of jquery uploader it is problem of server side.

Comment: ok. thank you. Ill look at my servers settings.

Comment: If you are using PHP, make sure you have set max_execution_time, max_input_time, upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini at high enough values. Uploads timing out point to max_execution_time being set too low.